# Mklink Via Drag And Drop Onto Batch

Tags: batch-file, drag-and-drop, mklink

What I need is a `batch file` that when I drag a file onto it it creates a `hardlink` with the link name the same as the file dropped onto the script with (HL) added to link name.

> e.g. test.txt [original] --> test(HL).txt [hardlink]

I've tried using this but it doesn't work.

`mklink /h %~n1(HL).%~x1 %~nxf`

How can I get this working?

Comment: The `~x` modifier already contains the `.`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got your target wrong:

```bat
@MkLink /H "%~n1[HL]%~x1" "%~1">Nul 2>&1
```

*I changed the parentheses to square brackets because I disagree with their use in file/folder names, that choice is of course yours to make.*

Comment: Could you go into detail on the target parameters please

Comment: **%1** is the dropped file with double quotes if necessary, **%~1** is the dropped file without outer double quotes. **%~n1** is the dropped file base name only. **%~x1** is the dropped file extension only.

Comment: What about the >Nul and 2>&1 part?

Comment: That simply redirects both stdout, _(1>)_, and stderr, _(2>)_, to `Nul` such that you don't see any output at all from the command. As the command window will close almost immediately you'll be unlikely to actually see that output anyhow.